How do we justify the Power Set Axiom?
The more I have been deeply pondering the foundation of mathematics the more it seems like the root of all evil and ambiguity comes from the (seemingly harmless) Power Set Axiom. I'm curious as to the defenses from an intuitive or maybe even platonic level (obviously formally, we don't really care about a justification). I want to be clear, I'm not a platonist, if I would be I feel like the only justified position would lean towards plenitudinous platonism.
My current understanding of the intuition behind mathematical objects (without extensively referring to the literature) is the following. We, as humans, have the ability to conceive of abstract objects almost more than concrete objects. E.g. when you look at a chair you perceive the chair, not the collections of atoms, so when elections change throughout the chair, your brain still perceives it as a chair. As a result of evolution, our minds are able to conceive the world as a simplified model and predict and infer further properties not immediately perceived. (Here I think our perception of time is critically important to this sense, as animals, we must be able to predict the future in certain possible worlds and reason about which would be most beneficial). The perception of time and the ability to create models leads to the foundational sense of induction; at each moment in time, we have the intuitive sense that we will persist as a being one second further.
The natural numbers can be thought of an abstract set of objects that capture this sense.

We posit some existence of a starting object 0.


At every object, we posit that there exists a new unique successor; distinct from all that came "before".


Lastly, a natural number can only be "created" or "brought into existence" by starting at 0, and sequentially perceiving the next successor until, at some point in time in the future, the sequence of operations halts (this captures the notion of finiteness).

It appears that those few sentences above capture exactly the same meaning that Peano's axioms do (specifically the second order axioms, as the last sentence has the same meaning as the second order induction principle). Do these objects exist external to us in a platonic or even Platonic way? I don't think so because I don't really know what that means. I think that these abstract objects were thrust into existence when we use language to ask the reader, student, etc. to consider their existence as abstract objects. This is no different than creating that abstract concept of a chair in our minds. Are there properties that can be inferred about those objects that are mind independent. I think so, yes; the process of learning those properties comes from deducing results from the very properties we defined them to have. Are those properties true? I don't know what that means, similar to "is induction true?". More importantly, are the Peano Axioms consistent? That is a concrete question whose negation is finitely verifiable. And foundationally, I think the sole reason to believe they are consistent, reduces to our experience of induction and time. Even if you are not a platonist about the natural numbers because according to Gödel, there are nonstandard models of first order PA, you still have reason to believe that PA is consistent.
This leads to set theory and the Power Set Axiom. Our concept of set comes from our perception of the world and the simple models we build in our head. The very intuition of being able to conceive of abstract objects leads to our intuition of sets. Ignoring advanced axioms of set theory (large cardinals, Determinacy, even Choice or Foundation) and considering just ZF - {Foundation}, most of these properties seem to coincide with our intuitive experience of sets in our mind. In ZF - {Foundation}, Extensionality is the only axiom that describes the nature of sets conforming to our experience of sets; their only distinguishing attribute is their collection of elements. The remaining axioms in ZF are existential. Comprehension, Pairing, Union also all coincide to our experience of sets. Replacement is extremely easy to accept intuitively. Even Infinity coincides with our intuition of induction.
Power Set however, seems to lack intuitive experience generally. We certainly have intuitive understanding of Power Set for finite sets. But for general sets, it doesn't even seem well-defined; it is ambiguous exactly what elements are in an arbitrary power set. Power Set is however necessary to prove the existence of uncountable cardinalities, but the ambiguity of such an operation leads to the independence of the Continuum Hypothesis (e.g. in Gödel's constructible universe L, the Power Set axiom is given a more specific meaning and CH is decided). But intuitively, I don't know what it means to take the power set of an arbitrary set. In different models or universes for set theory, the power set may have different cardinalities.
The most convincing justification I have heard is an appeal to the well founded hierarchy of sets. At any rank in the hierarchy, all sets "exist" as objects so for any set x, it "makes sense" to thrust into existence (just like induction) a new distinct object P(x) whose property is that only and every subset of x is an element of P(x). It most likely avoids any problems like Russel's paradox because we are growing the universe of sets upwards, at each rank creating new distinct sets with new distinct properties (elements) than those below. But as we go further into larger cardinalities, the intuitive experience of Power Set seems to break down.
The current position I am at is treating ZFC similar to that of Euclid's axioms, in that the ambiguity of Power Set can be related to the ambiguity of points and lines. And perhaps if one wants to create well-defined model to justify ZFC consistency, one can refer to the constructible universe L. L is limited (does not permit large cardinals) but at least it creates a intuitively possible model to justify the consistency of ZFC (although not finitistically, which would lead to the catastrophic end to set theory because of Gödel).
To summarize what I am looking for from this post: What are justifications of Power Set in the literature? I have undergone a project in this post to intuitively understand the natural numbers and universe of sets as abstract objects by relating it to our subjective experience of induction and distiction/collection. Is this meaningless? Formally, I have no problem accepting ZFC or PA. But in order for it to have any meaning outside of moving symbols around, I believe it must be tied to some cognitive concept of a specific universe of abstract objects. The referent when conceiving the natural numbers intuitively feel well-defined. But when trying to conceive of the well-founded hierarchy of sets, the Power Set axioms creates a fuzzy ambiguity the higher you climb in the hierarchy. I do not know what I am referring to when I imagine the universe of sets. Does Set Theory have such meaning?

See Joel David Hemkins etc, WHAT IS THE THEORY ZFC WITHOUT POWER SET?: "We show that the theory ZFC-, consisting of the usual axioms of
ZFC but with the power set axiom removed—specifically axiomatized by extensionality,
foundation, pairing, union, infinity, separation, replacement and
the assertion that every set can be well-ordered—is weaker than commonly
supposed and is inadequate to establish several basic facts often desired in its
context."

For any set X the existence of the power class(!) P(X) follows from the axiom of set-comprehension. But that P(X) is also a set(!) needs a further axiom, the power set axiom. - Do you ask for a motivation for the existence of P(X), i.e. a posteriori for a motivation of set-comprehension? Or do you ask why the power class of a set is again a set, i.e. for a motivation of the power set axiom?

The axiom of power set appears in most axiomatizations of set theory. It is generally considered uncontroversial, although constructive set theory prefers a weaker version to resolve concerns about predicativity and thus may be echoing your intuitive intuitionistic doubt consistent with Godel's constructible L. You could work in IKP where powerset axiom is removed: The theory denoted IKP is the constructive version of KP, the classical Kripke–Platek set theory without a form of Powerset...

You are not alone, doubts about powerset go back to Russell and Weyl, and it is rejected by predicativists, see discussions on Math SE and MathOverflow. The usual justification is pragmatic, "mathematicians tend to become interested in sets of things, functions whose domain or range consists of things, predicates on things, and so forth. The usual application of set theory requires there to be a set encompassing all of the choices... rejecting the axiom of powerset kills typical mathematical constructions."

For justifications of ZFC axioms, see the very informative Maddy, Believing the Axioms. On powerset, she quotes Hallet:"For the argument is not: we have a perfectly clear intuitive picture of the continuum, and the power-set principle enables us to capture this set-theoretically. Rather, the argument is: the power-set principle... was revealed in our attempts to make our intuitive picture of the continuum analytically clearer; in so far as these attempts are successful, then the power-set principle gains some confirmatory support."

@Conifold I actually just recently have been reading Maddy and found out that she is faculty at the university I am current at for grad school in CA. I would really like a chance to sit down and meet her especially after just reading her paper.

It is possible to construct the set of integers of from Peano's Axioms using the power set axiom among other ZF axioms. Is it possible to do so without that axiom?

The motivation, according to the iterative conception of sets - see also Von Neumann universe - is that sets "come into being" at stages.
There is an initial collection of individuals: objects that are not sets. At stage zero, we form all possible collections of individuals; if there are no individual, we can form only one set: the empty set.
And so on. Wrt the Power set axiom, assume that we have a set x that has been formed at stage S; it means that every member of x has been formed at some stage prior than S. So, every subset of x can be constructed at stage S.
Thus, at every stage following S, we can build a set containing all subsets of x.
See Boolos' The Iterative Conception of Set and Boolos' System S.

Welcome to the brave new world of Constructivism (Errett Bishop) and Predicativism (Hermann Weyl, Solomon Feferman, ...).  These schools indeed reject the generalized application of the power set axiom for some of the same reasons you mentioned.
Some mathematicians think it would be fruitless to justify the Power Set Axiom on any basis other than empirical.  Thus, the axiom is useful in many ways: (1) a seamless construction of the natural numbers starting from scratch (i.e., from the empty set); (2) clean definition of an ordered pair (this bumps you up in von Neumann rank); (3) therefore easy definition of Cartesian product, graph of a function; (4) if you want to do functional analysis, it is certainly useful to be able to form the set of functions satisfying a certain condition; (5) if you want to do topology, it is useful to be able to form the set of all open sets, etc.
In conclusion, we justify the Power Set Axiom by its usefulness in formalizing some empirically useful mathematics.
With regard to your comment

"The referent when conceiving the natural numbers intuitively feel well-defined"

note that some formalists (including Abraham Robinson) reject even such a referent; see some recent posts under the tag formalism.

So the standard Power Set axiom which just posits the existence of such a set can be thought of a weak statement. It is inherently non-constructive, but it is really just saying such a set should exist, not what it actually is. Similar to the existence of choice sets, which seem intuitively clear despite their non-constructiveness.

I think that the primary issue that I was having philosophically was the Power Set's function of infinitely expanding the well-founded hierarchy. How can we expand the domain this extremely without even knowing what they are being expanded to be. But this can be compared to the induction principle indefinitely thrusting the natural numbers towards infinity.

Would it be correct to say that the job of formalism is to define an approximate window of a platonic domain of objects? Discovering results from a formal system lead to "truths" about the platonic domain of objects if they existed. (Because formal systems are first-order, we will always be discovering "truths" that are also true about non-standard models as well).

You won't catch a Formalist characterizing her position in terms of either phlogiston, ether, or "window of a platonic domain".  The best historical precedent is Leibniz's "useful fictions".

The Power Set Axiom is the set theoretic Analogue To Exponentiation.
The same way the Union and Pairing Axioms allows us to have a successor of a set.
The Power Set let's us have exponentiation of sets.
The issue of a lack of constructability is taken seriously, and there is a lot of effort in trying to strengthen The Definable Powerset, to something that is compatible with Large Cardinal Axioms. We just, don't know how to do it yet.

This is the inner model project of Woodin, correct?

yes, the Ultimate L Program.

Let me comment a bit on the psychological aspects of this, since those seem to be critical to your question.

All objects are abstract objects; there's no such thing as a 'concrete' object. What I mean is that (e.g.) a chair is only a chair to the human mind. If you put a chair in the middle of a forest, the animals, birds, and insects passing by will not see a chair. They'll see something that they might walk around, sniff at, perch on, or even eat, but they won't recognize it as a instantiation of the class of objects called 'chairs'. Classes of objects define tools or resources — things we humans lump together mentally for particular purposes — and so that chair won't be perceived as a 'chair' until some human wanders by and thinks: "Why is there a chair in the middle of the forest?" A number may seem more abstract than a chair — you can't poke it with a stick, if you follow me — but ultimately a number is just a special kind of tool.

A mental object is by definition a focal singularity, an object of attention that is indivisible and separate from the background and surrounding objects. Indivisible means exactly what it sounds like: if you cut an apple in half the result is not two apples, but one apple in two pieces (note the ambiguities with non-specific nouns like 'rock' or 'water').

Numeracy doesn't begin with the natural numbers, or even the integers, though I understand why that approach is taken in mathematics. Numeracy begins with the basic relations 'more than', 'less than', and 'roughly equal to'. Very young children and many animals can distinguish changes in the relative size of groups of objects, roughly proportional to group size (i.e., larger groups of objects require larger differences to trigger the more/less perception). The unit integer, then, may be best defined as the smallest possible difference between non-equal groups.

The power set axiom is merely a consequence of °2. Any group of objects can be physically divided into two groups of smaller size in various ways (call them lefthand and righthand groups). The collection of all possible lefthand (or righthand) groups includes exactly all possible combinations of group members. That collection is finite for a group of finite size, because there is a specific indivisible object that makes up the smallest possible difference, and no non-group members are allowed. That constitutes the power set.


I'll leave the 'mathy' stuff to others.

I like this explanation. I definitely understand what you stated in 1. about abstract objects being the only thing that "exist" and was certain some motivation for me writing this post. What does it mean to have a statement be true about abstract objects? Is it just that it is semantically valid with respect to the properties we defined an object to have? The issue I primarily have with just asking a reader to consider an arbitrary abstract object is that of inconsistency or maybe being well-defined.

For example, I can posit the existence of an objects that is are arrows who point in only one direction. Then I say there is an object x that points up and points down.

It's immediately evident that this definition is incoherent, but we can we rely on intuition alone to discern if definitions are incoherent when referring to really complicated structures like sets... I'm a constructivist aren't I... I think I'm realizing.

One can retort and say that the intuitive concept of a power set is well-defined and coherent. Your description in 4. is equivalent to a representing function, where each subset of x is just an association which each element of x is colored with either {0, 1}. Then a power set is just all possible representing functions. That does feel really well founded and coherent even if it is never constructive for uncountable sets.

@BENG: well, in logic 'truth' is merely an extensible value: i.e., if we're given a set of statements that we already know to be true/false, we can manipulate them through logic to create statements that are derivatively true/false. That's syntactically-derived truth. But truth in the semantic sense has more to do with use-value. E.g., if I say: "that tree is tall", what I really mean is the mental object I'm referring to satisfies the use of the comparative term 'tall' in the context I'm considering.

@Beng: if it satisfies the use-value it's true, if it doesn't it's false.
